# Failing to connect client server to local network

Tags: java, sockets

I was learning socket programming in Java and had written a simple program for connecting a client server to a socket server on a local host. But every time when I run the ClientServer program it gives an error stating connection :refused.

I am enclosing both the client code and server code that i wrote and also enclosing the console output.

```
package Classes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ClientSer {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws UnknownHostException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",1029);
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());

        String str = "tEST mESSAGE";

        os.write(str);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

This is the server code:

```
package Classes;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketSer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss =  new ServerSocket(1029);

        Socket s = ss.accept();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String str = br.readLine();
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Classes.ClientSer.main(ClientSer.java:18)
```

Comment: Check the firewall configuration to make sure it's not blocking port 1029

Comment: You client tries to bind to the same port as the server which won't work. Also, your client never tries to connect to the server. Your code has no error checking, so it's very difficult to debug.

Comment: The `ServerSocket` _listens_ on port 1029.  The client socket binds ***to*** port 1029 using an available source port.  There's no conflict here.

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1. instead localhost when connecting to server on client side.

Answer (score 0):

In the server, do you know what interface it's listening on?

I would start the server and then use telnet to try to connect rather than your client. You might find the server is NOT listening on localhost. Or maybe it's listening on every interface (127.0.0.1 plus your local network). I just don't know if I trust SocketServer(portNumber).

I would consider creating an unbound SocketServer and then use socket.bind(), feeding it an InetSocketAddress object constructed with both host and port.